# Laptop wont boot although it's powered on

Tags: boot, laptop-repair

Girlfriends 5+ years old laptop that worked fine until last night is not booting, probably happened when I moved it with one hand from the bed to the desk without paying attention. When i power it on, its power led turns on, Capslock led blinks for a moment, hdd also blinks for a longer time right after it. I can hear with the hdd led, it attempts to boot, but nothing happens, nothing on screen either. I have just left it on for half an hour, and the fans were spinning where the gpu is when i came back, it was also quit hot. But i believe if it was overheating it would just turn off. I have tried switching the ram sticks or running with only one, running without rams, removing hdd and running without it either. Also tried unplugging everything amd the AC, holding power button for draining. A year ago it got its power jacket changed and i believe the guy also cleaned inside of it while at it, but other than that, it did not go to service.

Answer (score 1):

It's probably the video system. Either the GPU gave out or there's something up with the lcd.

You can find out which by doing the following.

Try finding an HDMI cable or some kind of video cable to plug your laptop into a tv or another monitor. If you get video on the monitor\tv then it's probably your lcd screen or some component of the lcd screen.

If the video hook up doesn't work then it's definitely your GPU.

BTW it is unlikely that lifting a laptop could cause this sort of damage unless you picked it up by grabbing the screen and swung it around or something.

Comment: Although i will give it a try once i find a cable and a screen, i really doubt this is the case. Wouldn't it be running properly but just not being able to show display if that was the case? In my case i can see that it does not even boot to windows, hdd led lights up for a sec, and then nothing.